# Memory refrencing Assembly Language

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, addressing-mode

i am a beginner in assembly language i understand many things till now but for many days i stuck in one section it's confusing to me and what make it worst that through the many pages i visited over internet  the information is twisted again ,this section is the **Addressing Modes** specifcally the **memory refrence** so for example in this [Addressing Modes in Assembly Language (IA-32 NASM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20608930/addressing-modes-in-assembly-language-ia-32-nasm)

two instructions seems same but the comment is diffrent

1. **mov esi, var**: Copies **address** of var (say 0x0040120e) into esi
2. **mov dword [eax], var1**: copies **value** in var1 into the memory slot
   specified by eax

both instructions deals with var or var1 which are labels but in comments for one it's mentioned it's copy the content ,while for the other it's copy the address.

and so another question i ask what will be the cooment for this instruction:

- **mov bx, [var]**

and what is the diffrence between these instructions also

- **mov [var], bx**-is this only applicaple if var is an array if not what it differ from the next instruction
- **mov var, bx**
- **lea eax, [var]** — the value in var is placed in EAX.[here it's mean value](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs216/guides/x86.html)
- **LEA EBX, [MY_TABLE]**[here its mean effective address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20608930/addressing-modes-in-assembly-language-ia-32-nasm)

so i need to know what is difference and is there is a confidence source that i can read from and be sure it's correct,by the way i'am using this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming),and NASM as assembler under windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `mov dword [eax], var1`: copies value in var1 into the memory slot specified by `eax`

Nope. If `var1` is a label, this will store *the address of* `var1` as a 32-bit value into the memory pointed to by `eax`. For example, if the address of `var1` is `0x04000000` and eax contains `0x12345678` then this would write `0x04000000` to memory at `0x12345678`.

---

> what will be the comment for this instruction: `mov bx, [var]` ?

```
; Move the word located at var into bx
```

(note: *"move"* in assembly really means copy)

---

> `mov [var], bx` is this only applicaple if `var` is an array? if not what it differ from `mov var, bx`?

Types aren't really enforced by the assembler. You can store anything anywhere (well, anywhere that your program is allowed to write to). So what you declared `var` as is largely irrelevant. There could be code located at `var` for all the assembler cares (that would probably not be such a good idea unless you really know what you're doing).

The difference to `mov var,bx` is that `mov var,bx` isn't a valid instruction. The address of `var` is an immediate, so this would be kind of like saying `mov 5, bx`, which obviously doesn't work.

---

> `lea eax, [var]` — the value in `var` is placed in `EAX`

No. *The address of* `var` is placed in `eax`. `LEA` means *Load Effective Address*. You give it a memory operand the same way as if you were going to access memory, but instead of the value at that address you get the address itself.

`LEA` can also be used to perform some simple arithmetic. For example, `lea ebx,[eax*4 + eax]` would calculate `eax*5` and put the result in `ebx`.

---

> `LEA EBX, [MY_TABLE]`  here its mean effective address

Yes. There's no difference between this and the previous example.

Comment: so i tell you what i understand and correct to me if any:if var is a label so using with brackets mov bx, [var] copy the contents and without brackets means the address -> mov dword [eax], var1,that's only if that label"var1 or var" is source operand in other word the right operand. But if it is the destination it has the opposit meanning using brackets means referencing the address as in mov [var], bx and without brackets means immediate value as in mov var,bx which is not applicable.

Comment: The brackets have the same meaning regardless of whether they're used on the source operand or the destination operand: `label` means the address of `label` (in NASM syntax anyway), and `[label]` means dereferencing that address. The address of a label doesn't _become_ an immediate; it _is_ an immediate. If you write something like `mov eax, 5` / `mov eax, var` you'll find that the assembler outputs the exact same opcode in both cases.

Comment: oh well ,i understand now ,it's dereference the address means that it access the content of that address.